# openssl connect error on non-blocking tcp with SSLv3 read finished B

Tags: c, openssl

I am using openssl on non-blocking tcp client. I am trying to establish 2 TLS connection, they are different sessions. The first is connected successfully. But there is a strange error for the second when connecting. Here is log for the second connection.

```
12:03:31.768 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Handshake: start
12:03:31.768 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: before/connect initialization
12:03:31.768 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 write client hello A
12:03:31.768 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Exit: error in SSLv3 read server hello A
12:03:31.768 TLS: INFO: SessConnect read blocked.
12:03:31.768 UTPT: INFO: tls conn[0x2000d] state read blocked.
12:03:31.768 UTPT: DEBUG: ConnProcTcpWr tls connecting.
12:03:31.782 UTPT: INFO: read tcp conn[0x2000d] of user[0x20008].
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 read server hello A
12:03:31.782 TLS: ERROR: verify error[18:self signed certificate] in depth[0].
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: issuer is </O=Self-signed certificate for kamailio/OU=cp/CN=cp.example.com/emailAddress=root@cp.example.com>
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: subject is </O=Self-signed certificate for kamailio/OU=cp/CN=cp.example.com/emailAddress=root@cp.example.com>
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 read server certificate A
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 read server done A
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 write client key exchange A
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 write finished A
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Loop: SSLv3 flush data
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Exit: error in SSLv3 read finished A
12:03:31.782 TLS: INFO: SessConnect read blocked.
12:03:31.782 UTPT: INFO: tls conn[0x2000d] state read blocked.
12:03:31.782 UTPT: DEBUG: ConnProcTcpRd tls connecting.
12:03:31.814 UTPT: INFO: read tcp conn[0x2000d] of user[0x20008].
12:03:31.814 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Write: SSLv3 read finished B
12:03:31.814 TLS: INFO: sess[0x4efdd3c] Exit: failed in SSLv3 read finished B
```

SSL fsm wants to read finished A, but failed on read finished B. Please help me to locate what would cause this happen.

Here is the error string when failed.

```
error:1408C095:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_FINISHED:digest check failed
```

I am not sure what does this mean.

Comment: [Did you check the OpenSSL error stack?](ftp://ftp.ulakbim.gov.tr/pub/openssl/docs/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html)

Comment: error:1408C095:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_FINISHED:digest check failed
It indicate failed on CRYPTO_memcmp in ssl3_get_finished. What does this mean?

Comment: The finished message is encrypted and has message authentication codes. The codes provided by the server don't match what the client had calculated. Start with `tcpdump` or `tshark`, and analyze the TCP packet flow, to make sure it matches what you expect. Then, you can move to `ssldump` to see if it reveals any additional clues as to what might be the error. Since there was a verify error, you might want to make sure your certificate is kosher as well.

Comment: When I only changed to block TCP before connect, it connected succesfully. It may related with read and write of socket.

Comment: Did you implement your own BIO? What does your non-blocking `SSL_connect()` handling code look like?

Comment: Thanks! I have found the error. I store the SSL_SESSION for reuse. But the condition only include IP, not port. For this reason, the 2nd TLS connection use the 1st SSL_SESSION. So it compute finished message including 1st connection's messages. This cause the digest check failed.

Comment: Cool, how does it explain it working for blocking `SSL_connect`?

Comment: I haven't check the openssl code. But I think in openssl for the first time to connect, it generate an new SSL_SESSION even you call SSL_set_session. While using blocking socket, there is no chance to change that SSL_SESSION during connecting.

Comment: See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_session_reuse